# Background Service after share button called in a random app

Tags: android, android-activity, browser, service, share

I want to create an app that can do something in the background (i have already programed that) when you press the sharebutton in for examplein: chrome, facebook, youtube,...

for now i have a activity that starts but I just want to open the brower on a specific page. without opening the activity for 0.5sec so i can get the url out of the intent and then open the browser.

I have seen that you need to use service but how can I get the resources out of the intent because you can't call `getIntent();`

This is my code.

public class Share extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (savedInstanceState == null && intent != null) {
        Log.d("INTENT", "intent != null");

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {
            Log.d("INTENT", "intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)");
            String url = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            System.out.println("url = " + url);
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", url);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("www.google.be");
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
        }
    }
}
```

}

**EDIT 1;**

```
public class ShareService extends IntentService {
    public ShareService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        Log.d("INTENT", "intent != null");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {
            Log.d("INTENT", "intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)");
            String url = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            System.out.println("url = " + url);
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", url);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.youtube-mp3.org/nl");
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
        }
    }
}
```

}

and my activity is this.

public class Share extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ShareService shareService = new ShareService("Share Service");
    shareService.startService(intent);
    finish();
}
```

}

this is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vanlooverenkoen.youtubtomp3">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="Share">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <service
        android:name=".ShareService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>
</manifest>
```

I get an nullpointer exception on sharService.startService(intent);

**CORRECT VERION OF MY ACTIVTY (WHERE THE FAULT WAS)**

```
public class Share extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startService(new Intent(this, ShareService.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create an app that can do something in the background (i have already programed that) when you press the sharebutton in for examplein: chrome, facebook, youtube

`ACTION_SEND` only goes to activities. You will need to have an activity, such as the one that you have working. That activity is welcome to start a service via `startService()` if it so chooses.

> how can I get the resources out of the intent because you can't call getIntent()

Your activity can pass whatever details it wants to the service via the `Intent` used with `startService()`. That service will get a copy of that `Intent` in `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: Do i need to use just a service or a IntentService? and then the activity wil be shown anyway if I use the service. Or do i need to change my manifest or my activity?

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren: "Do i need to use just a service or a IntentService?" -- either would be fine. `IntentService` is probably simpler, depending on what you want the service to do. "and then the activity wil be shown anyway if I use the service" -- you need to give some visual feedback to the user for the share operation. You are welcome to use `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`, skip `setContentView()`, and call `finish()` at the end of the activity's `onCreate()`, but do not be surprised if users get confused over why your app is not responding to the share request.

Comment: Oke yes this is what i need, i just need to skipContentView. because the app just opens something in the default browser so you know that something has changed. I will try this

Comment: i get a nullpointerexceptioin on startservice in my activity (check my rewritten post) EDIT 1

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren: **Never create instances of components yourself**. Create an `Intent` identifying your service (e.g., `new Intent(this, ShareService.class)`). Call `startService()` **on your activity**, passing the `Intent` as a parameter, to start your service. Along the way, get rid of the one-parameter constructor from `ShareService` (since it will never be used) -- if this is an `IntentService`, create a zero-argument constructor that chains to the one-argument superclass constructor.

Comment: @KoenVanLooveren: [Here is an example app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Service/Downloader) showing the use of `startService()` and an `IntentService`, as profiled in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android).

Comment: Oke nice :D indeed I know what you mean, it is the same like using startActivity();